# Texarea component doesn't trigger the submitform handler

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hook-form

I have a form in Next.js, using components I've made, they all work, but the TextArea one refuses to help triggering the submitHandler.

Once I remove this component the form executes properly.

My Input.js component is like this:

```js
<Input
  {...register('name', {
    required: true,
  })}
  label={t('common:forms.name')}
  />
```

And the component code is this one:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Input = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <label className={`input--text ${props.errors ? 'input--text--error' : ''}`}>
    <span className={props.errors ? 'color--red' : ''}>{props.label}</span>
    <input
      {...props}
      name={props.name}
      className={props.errors ? 'color--red' : ''}
      ref={ref}
      type={props.type}
      value={props.value}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      autoFocus={props.autoFocus}
    />
  </label>
));

Input.displayName = 'Input';

export default Input;
```

This component works well. I did a similar component for textareas, and it doesn't work. I don't know what I am doing wrong that the component doesn't work with react-hook-form.

```js
const TextArea = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
  <label className={`input--text ${props.errors ? 'input--text--error' : ''}`}>
    <span className={props.errors ? 'color--red' : ''}>{props.label}</span>
    <textarea
      cols={props.cols}
      rows={props.rows}
      ref={ref}
      className={props.errors ? 'color--red' : ''}
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
    ></textarea>
  </label>
));

TextArea.displayName = 'TextArea';

export default TextArea;
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the form to submit when you hit enter?

Comment: You are not spreading `{...props}` in your `<TextArea />` component like you do in `<Input />`. Without it, RHF can't link/add the form field to it's internal state.

Comment: @knoefel thank you, it worked! I didn't see it! So obvious…